# Perturbation theory with a continuous degenerate spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Let's assume that the unperturbated system $H_0$ is a free particle . It has the following energy spectrum $$ E = \frac{p^2}{2m} $$ and the set $\{ \vert k \rangle \} $ forms a complete basis for $H_0$.

Now, if we add a perturbation we obatin a new system that will be described by the following hamiltonian $$ H = H_0 + \lambda H_1 = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \lambda H_1 $$ where $\lambda$ is a small parameter.

I'm interested in evaluating the first order perturbeted ket $\vert \psi_1 \rangle$ that it will be something like $$ \vert \psi_1 \rangle = \vert \psi_0 \rangle + \lambda \vert \psi; 1 \rangle $$ where $\vert \psi_0 \rangle$ is the ground state of $H_0$, indeed $\vert 0 \rangle$. Since the energy spectrum is both continuous and degenerate, I can't use standard perturbation theory and I'haven't find yet a method to evaluate $\vert\psi_1\rangle$. Any suggestion?

Comment: By keeping $\lambda$ small and having $H_0$ for plane waves, it sounds like you mean to say that the energies of your particles are considerably larger than the thing they're interacting with, in which case this sounds very much like all sorts of classical QM: you want to be thinking of scattering matrices and reflection/transmission amplitudes, getting the unitary matrix corresponding to $H_1$ in the interaction picture or so?

Comment: Mmh, i think it could be the solution. The form of my $H_1$ is proportional to $p^4$, indeed it's $H_1 = p^4/m$. Do you think i can find out $\vert \psi; 1 \rangle $?